# Coding advice on Buttons and MediaPlayer (avoid choreographer skipped frames)

Tags: android

I've been making a soundboard app of my infant son's sounds. The app simply opens to MainActivity class where it displays a scrollable list of buttons that, when pressed, will playback a pre-recorded MP3 of my son screaming something.

Once it's debugging or running on my Nexus 7 there is a Choreographer error and somewhere between 50 and 90 frames are skipped. The warning is that the 'application may be doing too much work on its main thread'. On my device three random buttons refuse to play sound until the app is closed and re-opened but then another three random buttons refuse to work. This problem didn't occur when my app only had eight buttons in a simple LinearLayout (without ScrollView).

I'm a beginner to both java and Android programming but, from what I guess, my laughably poor code is taking too much memory to properly function. My question is either, how would you code a scrollable list of 33 buttons that play their own sound, or could someone teach me how to better my code, please?

MainActivity.java (showing only the first three buttons/sounds for this question):

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

final MediaPlayer ahh = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ahh);
final MediaPlayer dededeh = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.dededeh);
final MediaPlayer neganegabunbunbug = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.naganagbunbun);

Button bahh = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.Ahhhbutton);
bahh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ahh.start();
    }
});
}
}
```

And the activity_main.xml (again with only the first three buttons for this question):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tab1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Ahhhbutton"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@layout/button_shape"
            android:text="@string/button1a"
            android:textColor="#d1d1d1"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dededehbutton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@layout/button_shape"
            android:text="@string/button1b"
            android:textColor="#d1d1d1"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/neganegabunbunbugbutton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@layout/button_shape"
            android:text="@string/button1c"
            android:textColor="#d1d1d1"
            android:textSize="20sp" />



Button bdededeh = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.dededehbutton);
bdededeh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dededeh.start();
    }
});

Button bnaganagbunbun = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.naganagabunbutton);
bnaganagbunbun.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        neganegabunbunbug.start();
    }
});

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the layout. As your error said, you shouldn't do any long-term work on the Main-Thread.

The main-thread (or on Android the UI-Thread) handles interaction with the user. For the UI to not freeze and feel fast, you should execute long-term actions off the UI-Thread.

Also, the problem is not the actual playback, but you loading all media-files:

```
MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ahh);
```

As the docs for the [`create()`-method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create%28android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri%29) suggest:

> [...] When done with the MediaPlayer, you should call release(), to
>   free the resources. If not released, **too many MediaPlayer instances
>   will result in an exception.**

For the "off the UI-Thread"-thing, you have three options:

- Directly can create a [`Runnable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html)-implementing class that plays your sound and submit it to a [`ScheduledThreadPoolExecuter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) (maximum control, more code).
- Use an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) (Android exclusive) to play the song (fairly simple).
- If you want the sound-playback to continue even when the app is not currently in the foreground, use a [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) (most work)

So, what you should do is:

1. Store a List of your raw-file references (the `R.raw.ahh`) and **don't** load them directly.
2. When a song is selected for playback, call `create()` on that songs ID and start playback off the UI-Thread.
3. When done, call `release()` to release the resources.

Comment: Thank you Lukas for your detailed reply and for the time it took to type it all up. I really appreciate it. Since I'm still a beginner, I'll need some time to look into it, but you've given me a lot of options to research. I'll post again when I know more!